# CurVe document class: Adjust spaces between entries cross rubric or inside certain rubric without \vspace

Tags: spacing, macros, cv

I am using **CurVe** document class to create my CV.

I want to know if there is anyway to adjust the spaces between the entries (`\entry*[...]...`) as indicated by the **Figure 1**.

I know I can always put `\vspace` or `\vspace*` between the entries that I want to adjust. But I am looking for some universal way in which I can define all entry spaces cross the rubrics/sub-rubrics or within one certain rubric/sub-rubric (**Figure 2**).

**Figure 1. Illustration of the entry space**

[image: illustration of the entry space that I want to adjust]

**Figure 2. Adjust and unify the multiple entry spaces across or within rubrics/sub-rubrics**

[image]

Please check with the minimal example below.

0) The main.tex file:

```
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% main.tex file - compiling with this file will generate the pdf as shown in Figure 2
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\documentclass[loadonly, a4paper,11pt]{curve}

\usepackage[french]{babel} % this is necessary to have nicer formatting

\subrubricalignment{l} % sub-rubrics aligned at left
\prefix{~~} % here we use the empty space as the prefix for the entry titles


\begin{document}

\makerubric{cv_educations}
\makerubric{cv_experiences}
\makerubric{cv_publications}

\end{document}
```

Below are the code for the cv_educations.tex, cv_experiences.tex and cv_publications files used in the above main.tex file.

1) The cv_educations.tex file:

```
%------------------------------------------------------------------
% cv_educations.tex - save at the same directory with the main.tex
%------------------------------------------------------------------
%
\begin{rubric}{Educations}
%
%
\entry*[2005~--~2010]
    PhD at University A
%
\entry*[2001~--~2005]
    BSc at University B
%
\entry*[1999~--~2001]
    High school student at C school
%
%
\end{rubric}
```

2) The cv_experiences.tex file:

```
%-------------------------------------------------------------------
% cv_experiences.tex - save at the same directory with the main.tex
%-------------------------------------------------------------------
%
\begin{rubric}{Research experiences}
%
%
\subrubric{Postgraduate research}
\entry*[2012~--~2014]
    Job in A institute

    \begin{itemize} 
    \item[$\bullet$] responsibility 1
    \item[$\bullet$] responsibility 2
    \end{itemize}
%
\entry*[2010~--~2011]
    Job in B institute

    \begin{itemize}
    \item[$\bullet$] responsibility 1
    \item[$\bullet$] responsibility 2
    \end{itemize}
%
%
\subrubric{Graduate research}
    \entry*[2008~--~2009]
        Research topic A

        \begin{itemize} 
            \item[$\bullet$] responsibility 1
            \item[$\bullet$] responsibility 2
        \end{itemize}
%
    \entry*[2005~--~2007]
        Research topic B

        \begin{itemize}
            \item[$\bullet$] responsibility 1
            \item[$\bullet$] responsibility 2
        \end{itemize}
%
%   
\end{rubric}
```

3) The cv_publications.tex file:

```
%--------------------------------------------------------------------
% cv_publications.tex - save at the same directory with the main.tex
%--------------------------------------------------------------------
%
\begin{rubric}{Publications}
%
%
\entry*[1.]
    paper A
%
\entry*[2.]
    paper B
%
\entry*[3.]
    paper C
%
\entry*[4.]
    paper D
%
%
\end{rubric}
```

Comment: Hi, can you add a minimal code example that give us a perfect case for testing?

Comment: @Johannes_B Thanks for your kind reminding. I have just re-edited my post. At least it works on my computer. Please try out. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each rubric being in fact a tabular, you may play around with the `\arraystretch` command. For example, if you want to double the space between your entries in a rubric, just place

```
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
```

before the relevant `\makerubric` command. Caution, it will apply also to the following rubrics, so you'll have to use it again before their respective `\makerubric` if you want other spacings for them.

To personalize the spacing between two particular lines, you may enter the usual `\\[]` between them.

Comment: This works fine for adding spaces. However, with the above minimal example, I actually want to decrease the spaces between entries in the experience rubric. I have tried `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{-5}` and `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.1}`, but they seems no effect. Is there a way to shrink the entry spaces when I used `itemize` inside the rubric as showed in my minimal example?

Comment: @englealuze An `itemize` environment is not a `tabular`, so a change in `\arraystretch` doesn't work in this case. You may do something like placing the drastic `\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}` (or any small spacing you want in the argument) inside the `itemize` environment. See http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/List_Structures#Customizing_lists